# Freezing a Weeping Angel at long range

Tags: doctor-who, weeping-angels

Weeping Angels are 'quantum-locked' by observation. However, over great distances, observation doesn't happen instantaneously. If I were to set up with a telescope, light minutes away, could I observe a moving Weeping Angel? A light second? Light years?

Further, if the Angel were moving past me through space at some distant separation, where should I, the observer, look in order to freeze it? Where it was, causing the light to reach my eyes? Where it will be? Is it retroactively frozen, or frozen wherever it is right now?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you're applying too much physics to the problem. In quantum terms, observing something doesn't require any actual observer. To observe something is to measure it by interacting with it in some way. To observe a particle, you hit it with another particle. To observe a weeping angel, you hit it with photons *and* those photons have to enter some person's eyes. That second constraint is a completely fictional construct, so you can't apply actual physics to it.

Comment: It seems there does need to be an actual observer. There was a video camera on one, observing it, and it still moved when Amy wasn't watching it. It seems like it needs to be *seen* by eyes to keep it locked.

Comment: Note that this changes from episode to episode; in "Blink" the angels were quite intentionally never shown moving on-camera, as *the viewer* could see them.

Answer (score 0):

That's still observation. 
Technically, we're always looking back in time by fractions of a second, because it always takes light a fraction of a second to reach you. However, you are still observing the angel, and it cannot move. This would likely be the same regardless of how far away the angel is.

Comment: So if it's moving through space with respect to me, the observer, where should I look to freeze it? (Added question to original post to clarify my question.)

Comment: @rsegal In the Whoniverse time is not strictly linear, as we know.  Quite possibly looking at where it was (and appears to be) will sort of retroactively cause it to have been frozen for the part of its movement you observe.